# Скрипт сборщик информации.

Tags: скрипт

Всем привет! Задача стоит в том чтоб на сайте для клиентов был личный кабинет. Зарегистрированный пользователь заходил бы и мог увидеть позиции своего сайта в Яндексе и Гугле, тиц... и т.д. Есть два варианта  купить такой скрипт или написать самому. Вопрос в том, стоит ли иметь дело с готовыми?

Comment: В вопросе аж 2 вопроса целых, советую разделить их по приоритету.

Comment: ок, отредактировала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну тут как бе просто.

Пишем регистрацию и авторизацию ну и ЛК тут тоже подразумевается. Внутри можно прикрутить добавление сайтов пользователя, обновление инфы по сайтам и прочее прочее прочее.

Есть куча готовых скриптов для получения ТИЦ и PR сайта + AlexeRank.

Платными никогда не пользовался ибо писал сам.

Answer (score 0):

- 1 - Поискать готовые решения
- 2 - Написать самому
- 3 - Купить

Сперва попытайтесь найти готовые решения и если знания позволяют, то попробывать на их основе переписать или дописать под свою систему. Если же знания не позволяют, то п.2 отпадает сам собой!

Что касательно покупки скрипта, не спешите покупать готовые решения. Составьте ТЗ и найдите фрилансера который напишит вам скрипт под вашу систему, потому что готовые решения всеравно нужно внедрять, связывать данные и прочее!

Answer (score 0):

Я написал тож панельку для себя. Включает в себя Sape.Ru+Яндекс.Вебмастер+Гугл.Вебмастер+ регистраниция домена на моем сервере(настройки Apache+Bind и.т.д.) и все это на PHP)))

Comment: так кидай ее в паблик) шучу)

Comment: ожидай, может ТС обратится за помощью!

Comment: да не, он не предназначен для паблика))) советом могу помочь.